# Open a table for editing in a Console outside of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm trying to write a C# console application to convert a CSV of Lat,Lon data into a Table using insert/update cursors. However, I am having the darndest time figuring out how to get a reference to an ITable without first opening an instance of ArcMap. How would it be done?

The purpose is to open a table inside a geodatabase that *exists*. After I have a reference to it, I can create an insert cursor and turn the CSV into a proper table inside the geodatabase directly without bothering with Access (the devil).

Comment: Are you wanting to open the csv file as an ITable, or just the output table?

Comment: Just the output table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the [IGPUtilities](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n00000438000000) interface. It has methods for opening feature classes and tables from an ArcCatalog-style path which can save you dozens of lines of code.

The one you probably want is the [OpenTableFromString](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenTableFromString_Method/002n00000489000000/) method.

This is assuming the table exists, of course. If you need to create it then I am sure it's a bit more involved.

Comment: When it asks for an `ArcCatalog path`, it's just referring to what can be seen in the address bar of ArcCatalog, right?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! Thank you, this works perfectly.